# Lenovo IdeaPad 530s : Wifi goes off after working few minutes or doesn't work at all. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my Lenovo Ideapad 530s. At the beginning, wifi was working fine but about after 10 minutes wifi got disconnected and in the networking section, it wasn't showing any nearby Wifi router. I restarted the laptop then it started working again but again after 2 minutes wifi went off.

Sometimes even after restart wifi doesn't work. it never worked more than 10 minutes

Comment: Have you found a solution? I've read somewhere that Lenovo have weak wifi modems but I am not sure if it applies here.

Comment: It works if you change the default wifi power option. Forgot what command i used to do that though.